# extconf failed, exit code 1 error when installing [Ruby on Rails] 5 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to install Ruby on Rails v5 on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, following the instructions on the rails site:

http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html

When I run this:

```
sudo gem install rails --version 5.0.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I get the error `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension`. 
Here are parts of the output on my command line that might be useful:

```
current directory: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri

[...]


Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-da

rwin14.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:

[...]

 1 error generated.
    make[2]: *** [xmlIO.lo] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    ========================================================================
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may


    need configuration options.

[...]

    To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

      /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.8/mkmf.log


    extconf failed, exit code 1
```

And here's part of the mkmf.log file:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/x86_64-darwin14 -I/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward -I/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/include/ruby-2.3.0 -I.  -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wextra-tokens  -fno-common -pipe  conftest.c  -L. -L/Users/thanos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib     -lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc  "
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:395: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2:
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

I have no idea what is going on :(. Can someone help?

RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0p0.
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1

xcode-select is successfully installed.

Thanks!

Comment: when you run `gem env`, what version of rubygems do you have? Also, have you accepted the xcode license (`sudo xcodebuild -license`)?

Comment: RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.1. I've accepted the license but I still get the same error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
The error had to do with nokogiri. I installed it separately with the `-- --use-system-libraries` parameter:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
```

and I managed afterwards to install rails without errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I get `invalid option: --use-system-libraries` -- maybe you wanna update it ?

Comment: gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
doc: https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html#installing-using-standard-system-libraries

Answer (score 8):

http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html says they recommend installing with included libraries, not installing with system libraries.

So I tried (on Ubuntu) following the instruction there, and it worked

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: I had an error when executing 'sudo gem install sass'. 
Your answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating gems:

**gem update --system**

Answer (score 0):

I installed a newer version of rbenv (and ruby), use whatever version you'd like

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir="$(brew --prefix readline)" rbenv install 2.4.0
```

I updated my gems

```
gem update --system
```

and then was able to install rails without this nokogiri error

```
gem install rails
```